# Is it possible to run applet on old version Java

Tags: java, applet

I have simple HelloWorld app and I want to run it as applet.

Java 7 (update 45) is installed:
- Program Files/Java contains following folders: 
+ jdk1.7.0_45 
+ jre7

As I checked from here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_execution.html#jreVersion
**Java Control Panel** contains list of JREs which I can select to run an applet (in my case just one jre):
[image]

But, when I run applet in my browser it redirects me to the java 8 installation link (http://java.com/en/download/win8.jsp).

**So is it impossible to run applet on old java version or am I doing something wrong?**

Comment: which version did you use to compile the applet?

Comment: the same version 7.0_45. This is the only jdk installed on my computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check `minimumVersion` parameter of the `runApplet` function...it may require a later version of jre

Comment: yes, thank you very much. There was a problem with minimumVersion of my **deployJava.js** file. I completely forgot about it. I expected the problem in other place :)